Unable to use viewitem == and contextValue for TreeItem
I have the following TreeItem:
class Benchmark extends vscode.TreeItem {
    
    results: BenchmarkResult[] = [];

    constructor(name: string) {
        super(name);
        this.contextValue = 'benchmark';
    }

    addResult(real_time: number, time_unit: string, iterations: number) {
        let result = new BenchmarkResult(real_time, time_unit, iterations);
        this.results.push(result);
        this.collapsibleState = vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.Collapsed;
    }
}

I've set the contextValue as I then wish to show different menus depending upon the TreeItem.  I'm trying to then set this in my package.json like so:
"menus": {
  "view/item/context": [
    {
      "command": "benchmark-vscode.runBenchmarkBinary",
      "title": "Discover/run benchmarks",
      "when": "view == benchmarks && viewitem == benchmarkbinary"
    },
    {
      "command": "benchmark-vscode.runBenchmark",
      "title": "Run benchmark",
      "when": "view == benchmarks && viewitem == benchmark"
    }
  ]
}

But no combination of "when" values is doing what I expect.  I either get no menu at all, or all menus under one item.  What am I missing here?
N.B I also tried the inspect the context keys and I can't see my contextValue there.

I'm using contextValue in one of my extensions.  I see I simply use "when": "viewItem == TreeTab", without the view which seems unnecessary. And I set contextValue = 'TreeTab'; directly in my extending class - not in the constructor (and without this).  It works so you might give that simplified form a try.

Hah, you've actually inadvertently answered my question, it's viewItem and not viewitem

LOL, I didn't notice that.

As hinted to by the comments, it should be viewItem and not viewitem
